# Altering spatial query executed by Geoserver

Tags: geoserver

I am in the process of converting over from our existing map tile solution to geoserver.  We have lot of data stored in an Oracle DB and we've come to learn that using spatial queries is too slow / heavy.  In our current solution we introduced helper tables into the db that cross reference geometries to the tiles they appear on (using quad key tiling scheme as it works great for this case).  Once that is in place, it is a simple rewriting of the query from

```
SELECT ID,GEOM 
FROM tbl t
WHERE SDO_FILTER(t.GEOM, :1 , 'mask=anyinteract querytype=WINDOW') = 'TRUE'
```

to

```
SELECT ID,GEOM 
FROM tbl t 
where t.id in (select xr.tid from quad_xref xr where xr.quad_id = :1)
```

where quad_id is a parameter as part of the WMS request.  In our current solution the second query performs 20-50x better and hoping to understand if we can use this approach with geoserver

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this (if you must use Oracle) is to make a [view with an variable](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html). I'm assuming that you have a spatial index on the geometry column which should handle that look up for you.

That said the Oracle datastore gets very little love from the developers and you will almost get better performance from a PostGIS datastore.

Answer (score 0):

Running your query with a test data set on my site reveals no performance problems. Have you checked, whether you have a spatial index on t.geom? For an Oracle DB version 19c or higher I recommend creating the index using:

```sql
create index tbl_geom_six on tbl(geom) indextype is mdsys.spatial_index_v2;
```

If t.geom contains points only, you can also further optimize the index by adding parameters, such as:

```sql
create index tbl_geom_six on tbl(geom) indextype is mdsys.spatial_index_v2 parameters ('layer_gtype=POINT');
```

Please, also check whether you have enabled Spatial Vector Acceleration.

You can find more hints on optimizing the spatial performance in this slide deck:
https://www.oracle.com/a/ocom/docs/database/spatial-performance-and-best-practices.pdf